# Execute function from view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

i need help with my django project. I am trying to open folder from django view and I came up with idea which will execute python script which will handle this part, because for some security reasons Chrome is not able to directly open file explorer (program).

So I tried this.

detail.html looks:

```html
<form class="form" method='post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button style="width:100%;" type='explorer' name='explorer' value='explorer' class="btn btn-info btn-min-width"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Navigate to folder</button>
</form>
```

actions.py looks:

```py
def openexplorer():
    return os.system('explorer')
```

view.py looks:

```py
def detail(request, Pools_id):
    try:
        je = More.objects.get(pk=Pools_id)
    except More.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'rc/detail.html', {'more_identification': je})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'explorer' in request.POST:
            openexplorer()
```

I am rendring the page and i only want to execute the script when the button is clicked. Can someone please help? I think there is some error in view.py.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Server and client are running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes they are. I may have to put the if in try or before render, cause this all works for different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it. just put the if statement under try and it works fine :) That's cool

Comment: Oh yes, I should have seen that. `return` ends the function.